# From state chart to state table

Tags: rhapsody, statechart

Is there any way to get a `state table` from a IBM Rhapsody `Statechart` diagram?

Opening the generated `.rpy` file and trying to manually generate one is not such a good idea...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to view state-charts in a tabular format.
You need to change the state-chart property
`StatechartDiagram::StateDiagram::DefaultView` to `Tabular view`.

This feature is available since [Rhapsody V7.5](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/09/whatsnewinibmrationalrhapsodyv75/).

[image]

Details: [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSB2MU_7.5.3/com.ibm.rhapsody.designing.doc/topics/rhp_t_dm_vwing_stchrts_tabular.html)

Comment: And how do I export that `TabulawView` to some kind of `.txt` file? `Reporter/ReporterPLUS` does not have this option (it will not export the table itself, I only got `stereotypes/object model diagrams/components` information.

Comment: @MariusMarusanici You can print it as `.pdf`. I am not familiar with the Reporter, maybe you should ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize Rhapsody java api and write a code snippet to get details of elements of any given statechart.
A sample code is provided for [Creating a table matrix for statechart elements](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27043596#76).

```
import com.telelogic.rhapsody.core.IRPApplication;
import com.telelogic.rhapsody.core.IRPModelElement;
import com.telelogic.rhapsody.core.IRPProject;
import com.telelogic.rhapsody.core.IRPStateVertex;
import com.telelogic.rhapsody.core.IRPStatechart;
import com.telelogic.rhapsody.core.IRPTransition;
import com.telelogic.rhapsody.core.RhapsodyAppServer;

public class Statechart_Info
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        IRPApplication app = RhapsodyAppServer.getActiveRhapsodyApplication();
        IRPProject prj = app.activeProject();
        IRPModelElement moEle = app.getSelectedElement();
        IRPStatechart mySC = (IRPStatechart) moEle;
        String defTran=null;
        for (Object obj : mySC.getNestedElementsRecursive().toList())
        {
            if(obj instanceof IRPTransition)
            {
                IRPTransition myTran = (IRPTransition) obj;
                if(myTran.isDefaultTransition()==1)
                    defTran = myTran.getName();
            }
        }
        for (Object obj : mySC.getNestedElementsRecursive().toList())
        {
            if(obj instanceof IRPStateVertex)
            {
                IRPStateVertex mySV = (IRPStateVertex) obj;
                System.out.println("State: " + mySV.getName());
                System.out.println("\nIncoming Transition(s) to " + mySV.getName());
                for(Object obj1 : mySV.getInTransitions().toList())
                {
                    IRPTransition myTran = (IRPTransition) obj1;
                    System.out.println("Transition: " + myTran.getName());
                }
                System.out.println("\nOutgoing Transition(s) from " + mySV.getName());
                for(Object obj1 : mySV.getOutTransitions().toList())
                {
                    IRPTransition myTran = (IRPTransition) obj1;
                    System.out.println("Transition: " + myTran.getName());
                }
                if(mySV.getName().equals("ROOT"))
                    System.out.println("Transition: " + defTran);
                System.out.println("\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```